# What are some good uploader tool?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What is your favorite tool for uploading file?

In think that for my next project i'll use plupload (http://www.plupload.com/) but i wonders if there are others good project.

Thanks.

Comment: voting to close because the question is subjective :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of an open ended question!

http://timc.idv.tw/html5-file-upload/

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-html5-upload

http://www.3site.eu/jstests/upload/

[Google is your friend](http://www.google.com/search?q=html5%20upload%20control)

Comment: There's a lot of answer with my friend, i want to know what is your favorite and why? I'll test some anyway.